# mvn release:perform distributionManagement url

Tags: maven, deployment, maven-release-plugin

I have this configuration in my `pom.xml`:

```
<distributionManagement>
        <downloadUrl>http://mydomain/downloads/<downloadUrl>
        <repository>
            <id>Id</id>
            <name>Name</name>
            <url>scp://ipaddress/downloads/</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

When I do `mvn release:perform` and navigate to `http://mydomain/downloads/`, there is a directory hierarchy `com/my/application` that is my app groupId and, inside that, I have the .apk file (is an Android app).

Is there any way to deploy the apk in `http://mydomain/downloads/` instead of `http://mydomain/downloads/com/my/application` ? I mean, ignore the groupId.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't ignore the groupId cause this is the foundation on which a maven repository is based.

If you like to do it in an other way than you shouldn't use deployment of Maven. The solution can be to use a particular plugin like [wagon-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/)

Comment: Thank you :) I post my solution

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to khmarbaise, I found the solution using wagon plugin:

```
<build>
...
 <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
...

    <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>upload-apk</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>upload</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <fromDir>${project.build.directory}</fromDir>
                                <includes>${project.build.finalName}.apk</includes>
                                <url>scp://ipaddress/downloads/${artifactId}</url>
                                <serverId>downloads</serverId>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
    </plugins>

    </build>
```

Furthermore, I put `<serverId>` tag beacuse its credentials are stored in `settings.xml`.